# Why does MetaMask only show the gas fee as the transaction when I'm testing my dApp?

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask, ethers.js

I've been working on a presale dApp on the BSC testnet using solidity to deploy the contracts and obtain the ABIs, and using Preact/Ethers.js to build the interface.

I'm at the point where there are no real error messages in my build. The buyButton works as expected, and MetaMask opens. The console logs shows a connection to the presaleContract and helps show a number of other things working as expected. My issue however is that the MetaMask transaction only shows the gas fee. There is nothing else in the transaction relating to the spend currency nor the currency being bought. MM also confirms the presaleContract address as well as the function being called. Where am I going wrong here?

P.s. I am new to programming in general, let alone blockchain based stuff so apologies if my code is a bit mental!

[metamask txn screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6CRQ.png)

```
document.getElementById("buyButton").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const usdtEther = document.getElementById("usdtAmount");
  console.log(usdtAmount);

  try {
    const usdtX = usdtEther.value;
    const usdtAmount = ethers.parseUnits(usdtX, 6);
    const usdtString = usdtAmount.toString();
    console.log('USDT STRING:', usdtString);
    const buyProv = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);
    const buySign = await buyProv.getSigner();
    const buyContract = new ethers.Contract(presaleContractAddress, presaleContractAbi, buySign);
    const userAddress = await buySign.getAddress();
    const nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(userAddress, 'latest');
    const data = presaleContract.interface.encodeFunctionData("buyTokens", [usdtAmount]);  // Encoded 'buyTokens' function data


    console.log('userAdd', userAddress);
    console.log(buyProv);
    console.log(buySign);
    console.log(buyContract);
    console.log(usdtAmount);

    // Transaction options (gasPrice, gasLimit, etc.)
    const txOptions = {
      from: userAddress,
      to: presaleContractAddress,
      gasLimit: 200000, 
      gasPrice: ethers.parseUnits("20", "gwei"),
      chainId: 97, 
      value: 0,
      nonce: nonce,
      data: data,
    };

    console.log('txOptions:', txOptions);

    txOptions.sendTransaction = true;

    await buySign.sendTransaction({
      to: presaleContractAddress,
      ...txOptions,
    });


   
    alert("Tokens purchased successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error purchasing tokens:", error);
    alert("Error purchasing tokens. See console for details.");
  }
});
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract Presale is Ownable, Pausable, ReentrancyGuard {
    IERC20 public kooToken;
    IERC20 public usdtToken;

    uint256 public constant presalePrice = 793700000000000; // This represents 0.0007937 USDT with 7 decimal precision
    uint256 public constant tokensToSell = 6300000000000000000000000000; // 6.3 billion KOO with 18 decimals

    uint256 public totalTokensSold;

    event TokensPurchased(address indexed buyer, uint256 amount);
    event TokensWithdrawn(address indexed owner, uint256 amount);
    event FundsWithdrawn(address indexed owner, uint256 amount);

    constructor(address _kooToken, address _usdtToken) {
        kooToken = IERC20(_kooToken);
        usdtToken = IERC20(_usdtToken);
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 usdtAmount) external whenNotPaused nonReentrant {
        require(usdtAmount > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");

        uint256 tokensToBuy = usdtAmount * 10**7 / presalePrice; // Calculate tokens to buy using the 7 decimal precision of the price
        uint256 remainingTokens = tokensToSell - totalTokensSold;

        require(tokensToBuy <= remainingTokens, "Not enough tokens left for sale");

        // Transfer USDT from buyer to this contract
        require(usdtToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), usdtAmount), "USDT transfer failed");

        // Transfer KOO tokens from this contract to the buyer
        kooToken.transfer(msg.sender, tokensToBuy);

        totalTokensSold += tokensToBuy;

        emit TokensPurchased(msg.sender, tokensToBuy);
    }

    function withdrawUnsoldTokens() external onlyOwner {
        uint256 unsoldTokens = tokensToSell - totalTokensSold;
        require(unsoldTokens > 0, "No unsold tokens left");

        kooToken.transfer(owner(), unsoldTokens);

        emit TokensWithdrawn(owner(), unsoldTokens);
    }

    function withdrawUSDT() external onlyOwner {
        uint256 contractBalance = usdtToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(contractBalance > 0, "No USDT to withdraw");

        usdtToken.transfer(owner(), contractBalance);

        emit FundsWithdrawn(owner(), contractBalance);
    }

    function withdrawAccidentallySentTokens(address _tokenAddress) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        uint256 contractBalance = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        require(contractBalance > 0, "No tokens to withdraw");

        token.transfer(owner(), contractBalance);

        emit TokensWithdrawn(owner(), contractBalance);
    }

    function pause() external onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    // Fallback function to receive Ether (if needed)
    receive() external payable {}
}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract kooToken is ERC20Burnable, Ownable, Pausable, ReentrancyGuard {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public presaleContract;
    address public liquidityWallet;
    address public rewardsWallet;

    uint256 public buyFeePercent = 1;
    uint256 public sellFeePercent = 1;

    constructor() ERC20("HATO", "KOO") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 21 * 10**9 * 10**18); // 21 billion initial supply
    }

    function setPresaleContract(address _presaleContract) external onlyOwner {
        presaleContract = _presaleContract;
    }

    function setLiquidityWallet(address _liquidityWallet) external onlyOwner {
        liquidityWallet = _liquidityWallet;
    }

    function setRewardsWallet(address _rewardsWallet) external onlyOwner {
        rewardsWallet = _rewardsWallet;
    }

    function setBuyFeePercent(uint256 _percent) external onlyOwner {
        require(_percent <= 1, "Buy fee cannot exceed 1%");
        buyFeePercent = _percent;
    }

    function setSellFeePercent(uint256 _percent) external onlyOwner {
        require(_percent <= 1, "Sell fee cannot exceed 1%");
        sellFeePercent = _percent;
    }

    function _transfer(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override nonReentrant {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        uint256 fee = 0;
        if (
            msg.sender == presaleContract ||
            msg.sender == owner() ||
            msg.sender == address(this) || // Allow the contract itself to use tokens during buy/sell
            paused() // Allow both owner and presale contract to use tokens when paused
        ) {
            fee = 0; // No fees for owner, presale contract, and the contract itself
        } else if (recipient == address(this)) {
            fee = amount.mul(buyFeePercent).div(100); // Buy fee
        } else if (sender == address(this)) {
            fee = amount.mul(sellFeePercent).div(100); // Sell fee
        }

        uint256 transferAmount = amount.sub(fee);

        // Check if the sender has a sufficient balance to cover the transfer and fees
        require(balanceOf(sender) >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        require(balanceOf(sender) >= fee, "Insufficient balance for fees");

        super._transfer(sender, recipient, transferAmount);

        if (fee > 0) {
            super._transfer(sender, liquidityWallet, fee.div(2));
            super._transfer(sender, rewardsWallet, fee.div(2));
        }
    }

    function pause() external onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }
}
```

I'm kind of at a loss with this one, it's taken me a while to get to this point with a lot of troubleshooting and error handling - it feels like I'm almost there but I cannot figure out what the issue is. Searching online for already existent posts hasn't helped, and neither has ChatGPT (but when does it ever!) As mentioned, I'm new to this so it's difficult to identify exactly what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what went wrong, you need to understand how does `usdtToken.transferFrom()` work.

ERC20 contracts or any smart-contract for that matter need direct interaction from the owner wallet to transfer any tokens. But as `usdtToken.transferFrom()` is meant to be called from other indirect sources, there is another accompanying function `usdtToken.approve()` which needs to be called before invoking `usdtToken.transferFrom()`.

The `usdtToken.approve()` is to be called separately before calling any functions that will invoke `usdtToken.transferFrom()` internally.

***Solution***

you need to call `USDTContract.approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)` in the JS before calling `PreSaleContract.buyTokens(uint256 _value)`

***Refer***

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145356/understanding-approve-and-transferfrom-confused

and next time post your questions in [ethereum.stackexchange.com](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks! I've cleaned my code up a lot now. Now I'm in a situation where the USDT approval triggers in MM (being described as a contract interaction), but again it shows no transaction other than a gas fee. I can successfully approve this, to which the BUY TOKENS function opens in MM shortly after (displaying BUY TOKENS interaction) - again with nothing but gas fees showing. The functions are being correctly identified in my IDE, my console log and MM, but there's something still missing here unfortunately!